# cocos2dx project wants latest build tools v141 (using VS 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cocos2d-x

So some history. I had Visual Studio 2015 Community installed on my computer from about a year ago. I decided I wanted to use cocos2dx and Visual Studio 2017 Community. I installed VS2017, however this was not successful in building a cocos2dx test app, I uninstalled VS2017, and tried with the older VS2015 which seems to be more compatible with cocos2dx.

When I attempt to build a project either in VS2015 or by using the command line 'cocos compile -p win32 -m release -o bin' I first get the error:

> Required VS version : [2013, 2015]
> running: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\git\cocos\test2\MyGame\proj.win32\MyGame.sln" > /Build "Release" /Project "MyGame"'
>
> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Error running command, return code: 1.

(Which seems like a bug with cocos CLI not being designed for running on the Windows command line unless the path to devenv.com doesn't contain a space - which has been a Microsoft tradition since Windows 95. weird)

Anyhow running the command directly:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\git\cocos\test2\MyGame\proj.win32\MyGame.sln" > /Build "Release" /Project "MyGame"

I get the error:

> The build tools for v141 cannot be found. Install v141 to build using the v141 build tools.

and the error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

So this suggests I do not have v141 build tools. There is no option in Visual Studio to 'Retarget Solution'. After doing some digging it turns out that v140 corresponds to Visual Studio 14.0 aka VS2015, and v141 corresponds to Visual Studio 15.0 aka VS2017. Thus me installing VS2017 and uninstalling it has caused Windows 10 (or cocos2dx's tools) to think it should still use a non-existant v141 build tools.

I can't seem to 'reset' windows or cocos2dx to use v140 as default. I can't even see where (which setting, file, configuration etc.) tells VS to try to use a particular version.

Also using VS2015, loading the cocos2dx generated solution ('cocos new...'), going into project properties->General. For platform toolset i see:

> 1. Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
> 2. Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp) <-- default
> 3. inherit from parent or project defaults...

Trying to change this option and hitting apply results in the error:

> An error has occurred while saving the edited properties listed below:
> One or more values are invalid. Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: userSuppliedValue

I've also tried to uninstall both VS2015 and VS2017, deleting the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015/2017 directories from Program Files (x86) and Program Files, as well as MSBuild. Essentially anything to try to make it seem fresh.

I've a feeling that somehow my computer has been corrupt, and the only remedy is to reinstall Windows 10 (or another operating system). As I'm pretty well stuck having spent the past 4 days trying to essentially do what should be a 5 min 'Hello World' with cocos2dx on Visual Studio.